# Hibernate - Is it possible to have an entity based in a function result instead of a table?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate 6 with SpringBoot 3 and I am trying to have an entity based in a function result rather than a table. From my research I was led to believe that something like the following would be valid:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "myFunction",
    procedureName = "my_function",
    resultClasses = MyEntity.class,
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "param1", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "param2", type = Integer.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
    }
)
public class MyEntity {
    // entity fields and methods
}
```

But If I try to run the application I get the following:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [MyEntity]

I continued my research and later I tried something along the lines of:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
  name = "getEmployeeData",
  procedureName = "get_employee_data",
  parameters = {
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "p_employee_id", type = Integer.class),
  },
  resultSetMappings = "employeeDataMapping"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
  name = "employeeDataMapping",
  classes = {
    @ConstructorResult(
      targetClass = Employee.class,
      columns = {
        @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Integer.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "name", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "age", type = Integer.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "salary", type = BigDecimal.class),
      }
    )
  }
)
public class Employee {
  @Id
  private Integer id;
  
  private String name;
  
  private Integer age;
  
  private BigDecimal salary;
  
}
```

The result was exactly the same.

Few notes:

- The table does not exist, all I have to work with is this parameterized function in the db
- Currently we have in place a very sketchy hack where we use `@Subselect` in conjunction with `@Filter` and an `Interceptor` to edit the `PreparedStatement` to be able to have this entity usable
- My goal is to remove this hack and actually use the tools the framework provides but at this point I am wondering if this is in fact possible

Any idea, advice or clue regarding the matter?

Thank you

Comment: If your function is not related to a table respective entity then don't use NamedStoredProcudureQuery annotation. Use Procedure annotation instead. If you share the function code then I can provide a Java code example.

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/jpa-21-namedstoredprocedurequery-annotation-example/

Comment: @Mar-Z Not sure if I understood what you mean. I cannot provide the postgres function code but it's a function called with arguments which should have the results mapped to an entity.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant is that if you have no table in the database then you should not use the entity class for results. Because in Spring Boot JPA each entity needs a database table.

If your database function has a complex data structure for results (not primitive like number or string) then you should define a POJO class (like entity but not annotated as entity). And use it for the function call. Something like this:

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "get_employee_data")
Employee getEmloyeeData(Integer emloyeeId);
```

Please note: more configuration could be needed depending on your function output parameters definition.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure if this is could be a solution or not. I am fairly new to JPA and I am trying to improve a project that I inherited. My main concern here is that we are using this "false" entity in some generic implementations that I am not sure could deal with an object that it's not an JPA entity in the same. I will have to give it a try and see what results I get.